# regular expressions and whitespaces in re library

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have this:

```
import re
s = '     Hello,     world     '
re.sub(r'\S+', 'a', s)
```

it gets me

```
'   a    a    '
```

as expected (greedily taking longest substring with at least one \S (any unicode non-whitespace) character, but

```
re.sub(r'\S*', 'a', s)
```

gets me

```
'a a a a a a a a a a a a'
```

which seems weird to me. Where did all those whitespace substrings go? What is really going on here?

E: I understand that it puts string 'a' every time it matches an empty string, but I can't follow why it doesn't leave whitespace substrings alone, as \S* shouldn't be a match for them, as opposed to \s*

Comment: `re.sub(r'\S+', ' ', s)` gives me an empty string without any `a` characters

Comment: The explanation is the same as in the linked dupe. `\S*` matches a location before a non-matching symbol, ie. before any whitespace symbol. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLUDpa/1) to see where the matches are, hence, the result.

Comment: ^ same here. Which makes sense, because \S+ matches everything that is not whitespace, and replaces it with whitespaces.

Comment: corrected to `re.sub(r'\S+', 'a', s)` as it should be